# PHP - Get info from api T00000 AS DATE should not be there

Tags: php, string, date

hello I want to remove this T00:00:00 from the Date.
Start Date: 2022-03-25T00:00:00

```
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $startDate=   $value['startDate']
        echo "<li><h5>Start Date: $startDate</h5></li>";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243027/discussion-on-question-by-trevor-scholtz-php-get-info-from-api-t00000-as-date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split by character 'T' and take the first part of it.

```php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $startDate = explode("T", $value['startDate'])[0];
```

Comment: let me try  I  will let u know now

Comment: Your a genious thanks man

Comment: genius made error

Comment: $startTime= $value['startTime'];   // How bout time then im done /// End Time: 16:00:00 the last two zeros

Comment: $startTime = substr($value['startTime'], 5);

Comment: End Time: : 00 is  result and start time not showing

Comment: i have start and end time so it gives that result

Comment: End Time: :00   this exact result

Comment: $startTime = substr($value['startTime'], 0, 5);

Comment: will try and let u know

Comment: foreach( $data_input as $value){  //////////

 echo "<div class='col-md-2' >";  ////
 echo "<div class='card card-custom1 bg-white border-white border-0'>"; ////
//
 echo "  <center><i class= 'fa fa-clock-o '  style='font-size:30px'></i><center>";/////
////
echo "<h3>Time Slots:</h3>";////
    echo "  <h4>$value </h4> "; /////
    /////
    echo"</div>";////
echo "</div>";////

Comment: my time slots are not assigned to a variable  only with value and that displays all my time events so i need the last zeros gone with $value then im done
Time Slots:
08:10:00 To 08:20:00